# How to create ng-bootstrap modal with persistent component?

Tags: angular, typescript, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement a modal with angular following this tutorial (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal - section "Components as content"), but I want the component displayed in the modal to persist it's state once closed for the next time it's opened.

I've created a simple Plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/EJyZ6nF5WVAS9bvQycQe?p=preview

What I want to achieve is that a call to open() after a call to openA() will show the text "Hello, A!" but it's not keeping the state.

```js
openA() {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
  modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'A';
}

openB() {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
  modalRef.componentInstance.name = 'B';
}

open() {
  const modalRef = this.modalService.open(NgbdModalContent);
}
```

¿How can this minimum setup be created? ¿Or which angular documentation do you recomend to understand what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

Every time a new modal is opened with a component as content, the said component will be re-created (and destroyed on modal close). In this sense you can't "persist" component instances.

What you should be doing instead is to keep around *model* (data) that is driving component's display and behaviour.

Comment: The case is that the component contains another component that takes a lot of time to initialize itself before it's ready to be shown (very complex form), that's the reason I want to "persist" the component. ¿Could the modal be hidden until the component is ready at least? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Open parent model with **windowClass** option

```
const parentModalRef = this.modalService.open(ParentModal, {
  centered: true,
  windowClass: 'refererToParent',
});
```

This will add a class "refererToParent" to your parent modal window.
Before opening your ChildModal remove class "show" from your parent modal window. Open then your ChildModal **without backdrop**

```
parent = document.getElementsByClassName('refererToParent').item(0)!;
parent.classList.remove('show')
const childModalRef = this.modalService.open(ChildModal, {
  backdrop: false
});
```

Set a listener on *childModalRef* that will append class 'show' once your ChildModel is closed.

```
childModalRef.closed.subscribe(() => parent.classList.add('show'))
```